# What do the colors in gmapping mean?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty new to ROS and I've been trying to do gmapping for turtlebot2 and turtlebot3 on
Ubuntu 16.04 ROS-kinetic. I have been successful, however I've been trying to figure what
the different colors mean. I've tried googling the answer but to no avail.
Below are two links to see what I'm talking about.
The first one is an image of turtlebot2 gmapping
and the second one is of turtlebot3 gmapping.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

Could anyone explain what the different colors that surround the objects mean for each of the images?

What does the light blue, dark blue, red and pink colors in turtlebot2 gmapping mean ?

In turtlebot3, there are light blue colors surrounding the objects but why are there light blue spots or circles on places that have no objects?

Your answer would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310467/what-do-the-colors-in-gmapping-mean?/) by [Orl](https://answers.ros.org/users/38968/orl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
Could you please attach your images directly to the question? I've given you sufficient karma for that.

Thanks.

**Comment by [Orl](https://answers.ros.org/users/38968/orl/) on 2018-12-12**:
Sure thing. Thanks for the karma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

---

Originally posted by [Orl](https://answers.ros.org/users/38968/orl/) with karma: 36 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-09**:
Link-only answers should really be discouraged. Can you please provide an overview, quote, something to give more information?